# Is it possible to self transfer from arrivals to departures in Terminal 1 of Dubai Airport? (DXB)

Tags: transit, dubai, dxb, airport-terminals

I will be arriving in Dubai Terminal 1 with British Airways at 07:45. I need to go catch an Indigo flight from Dubai Terminal 1 departures at 11:45 (Time gap of 4hrs).Is it possible to walk from Dubai Terminal 1 arrivals to departures?
P.S. I have checked in luggage.

Answer (score 3):

While in normal circumstances this shouldn't be a problem at all, remember that **in case of disruption you are on your own**.

You will need to:

- deplane
- get to passport control, queue, get through
- wait for your bags
- go through customs
- get to departures and to the check-in area for your second flight
- queue and **check in before the check-in deadline (75 minutes before departure)**.
- then go through security and to your gate and board before the door closes (25 minutes before departure)

So in reality **the critical path is not 4 hours but 2h45 to check-in**.

I also haven't counted any Covid-related formalities, I don't know what they are and where they take place in Dubai. I'm also assuming you are allowed to enter Dubai (don't need a visa or have one if needed).

Still **plenty of time if your incoming flight is on time and everything goes well**, but if your flight is late, or there are any issues at passport control, baggage claim, customs, or Covid-related checks, it can quickly become quite tight.

Remember that if you miss the check-in deadline, the airline will consider you a **no-show*. In most cases (this seems to be the case for all Indigo fares) this will mean **your ticket is cancelled** (sometimes further flights on the same ticket are cancelled too), and you may need to **book and pay for a new ticket on the next flight, at the last minute** (flights may be fully booked, or more likely they are going to be **much more expensive**). In the worst case you may have to stay overnight. All of this is **out of your pocket** (unless you have travel insurance which specifically covers this case).

Also remember that **schedules can change** (especially these days) and Indigo may move your flight to an earlier time (or BA to a later time), in which case you won't have much recourse if the other flight is not refundable or at least changeable (there will probably be fees/penalties attached, and they will usually re-bill at the **current** price of the flight, not the time you booked initially).

Self-connections may be cheaper, but they are risky. Do it only if you are prepared to handle the consequences.

Answer (score -1):

According to the map at https://www.dubaiairports.ae/while-youre-here/map?facility=5&level=1&poi=, the Departures area is just next to the Arrivals area in Terminal 1, so you should have enought time (walking distance should be around 300 - 400 metres.

Comment: The actually walking is the smallest problem here